# Cloud KMS with support for Solana (ED25519)

Tags: secure-key-storage

So, my team and I are currently building a product on the Solana network and we would like to use a Key Management Service. Could anyone please recommend a cloud Key Management Service (KMS) that supports Solana. i.e a KMS that supports the ED25519 signature algorithm.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As of **March 18 2024**, [AWS KMS does not support Ed25519 curves](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/asymmetric-key-specs.html#key-spec-ecc).

> AWS KMS supports the following ECC key specs for asymmetric KMS keys:
>
> - ECC_NIST_P256 (secp256r1)
> - ECC_NIST_P384 (secp384r1)
> - ECC_NIST_P521 (secp521r1)
> - ECC_SECG_P256K1 (secp256k1)

Ed25519, Solana's curve which is also a [safe curve](https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/) is not currently listed at this time.

But if you're reading this in the future, you should **check the [AWS KMS list of key specs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/asymmetric-key-specs.html#key-spec-ecc)** as AWS add more features.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few options to choose from; however, AWS(Amazon Web Services) KMS supports the ED25519 signature algorithm, making it a good choice for Solana applications.

Comment: Q: What kinds of asymmetric signing algorithms are supported?
When using RSA key types, AWS KMS supports the RSASSA_PSS_SHA_256, RSASSA_PSS_SHA_384, RSASSA_PSS_SHA_512, RSASSA_PKCS1_V1_5_SHA_256, RSASSA_PKCS1_V1_5_SHA_384, and RSASSA_PKCS1_V1_5_SHA_512 signing algorithms.
When using elliptic curve key types, AWS KMS supports the ECDSA_SHA_256, ECDSA_SHA_384, and ECDSA_SHA_512 signing algorithms.

But here is an answer to a question about supported key types on AWS and ED25519 isn't listed. This is from the Q&A section of AWS KMS.

Comment: @ellie A statement alone with no references isn't generally considered a good answer. Can you add a reference showing that AWS KMS (not other AWS features, like EC2, but the KMS) supports Ed25519 if this is the case?